# How to valdiate each json array objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json

How to validate each of the names, ages and descriptions irrespective of json array index? It will kind of search that we need to validate on the basis of name, age and description with age is matching or not.

```
   [
      {
        "Name": "Shobit",
        "transactionDate": 1623049638000,
        "age": "18",
        "description": "My item for new collection addition into system with age 18"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Neha",
        "transactionDate": 1623049877000,
        "age": "20",
        "description": "My item for new collection addition into system with age 20"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Check about JSONSchema, it's what you need for Json validation (both for content and structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data to `JSONArray` and check each item as a JSONObject for example

```java
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length() ; i++) {
    JSONObject user = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = user.getString("Name");
    long transactionDate = user.getLong("transactionDate");
    int age = user.getInt("age");
    String description = user.getString("description");
    // Validate here
}
```

Or move the validation to another method for example

```java
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length() ; i++) {
    JSONObject user = array.getJSONObject(i);
    boolean isValidInfo = isValidateUser(user);
}
```

Validation method

```java
public boolean isValidateUser(JSONObject user) {
    String name = user.getString("Name");
    long transactionDate = user.getLong("transactionDate");
    int age = user.getInt("age");
    String description = user.getString("description");
    // Validate here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For java you can use the library "org.json"
Add in your pom.xml dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now you can use the next solution with java 8 :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonArray);
    IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length()).forEachOrdered(index -> {
        // below the solution @AmrDeveloper

        JSONObject user = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
        String name = user.getString("Name");
        long transactionDate = user.getLong("transactionDate");
        int age = user.getInt("age");
        String description = user.getString("description");
        // Validate here
    });
```

OR USE other libraries.

Example with Jackson

Add dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Create POJO:

```
public class User {
private String name;
private Long transactionDate;
private Integer age;
private String description;

public User(String name, Long transactionDate, Integer age, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    this.age = age;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getTransactionDate() {
    return transactionDate;
}

public void setTransactionDate(Long transactionDate) {
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Create method:

```
public <T> Optional<List<T>> buildListObjectsFromJson(String jsonObjectsList, Class<T> clazz) {
    LOGGER.info("Try to build list objects from json....");
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<T> objectsList = objectMapper
                .readValue(jsonObjectsList, objectMapper.getTypeFactory()
                        .constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, clazz));
        LOGGER.info("Objects list created successfully! List size = {}", objectsList.size());
        return Optional.of(objectsList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Can't build List objects by json: {}", jsonObjectsList);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

And create use next example:

```
List<User> users = buildListObjectsFromJson(yourJsonArray, User.class).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
```

This way you can work with this data as a collection.